# Please help with evaluating an integral using the Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, residue-calculus

Use the Residue Theorem to evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{∞} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} \, dx$.

Using the trig identity, this is how far I've gotten:
let $F(z)=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1-(e^{2iz})}{z^2}$, and then $\int_{0}^{∞} F(z) \,dz$.

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. please help!

Comment: Dear Kelly, One comment is that in these kinds of questions, it is often helpful to replace the integral over the half-line to the integral over the full line.  In your case this is easy, because the integrand is even, so the integral you want can be rewritten as $1/2$ times the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.  Regards,

Comment: Here is the [same problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215401/improper-integral-of-sin2x-x2-evaluated-via-residues/215416#215416).

Comment: You can find the method you want [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141695/how-to-calculate-the-integral-of-sin2x-x2).